# Can't install C++ library

Tags: installation, c++

I want to install the C++ library, but the terminal keeps asking me to insert the CD for installation. What CD?

Here is the terminal code I used to attempt to install with:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

After I enter in my password and hit <kbd>y</kbd>, it says: Media change

Why does it say that? Can anyone help me either with this problem or find another way to install the C++ Library?
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you have?  12.04?  12.10?  13.04?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is because you've used CDs/DVDs to install your system instead of online repositories. When you try to use the package manager it's referring to those CDs.

You might want to add Ubuntu repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list or /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Default contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` contents for Ubuntu Precise installed using netboot images is listed below:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
```

Then run `apt-get update` and install the buil-essential package as you tried doing it earlier.